# Cakephp unit test how I will write a test method for test buildRules

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to write a test case for below codes

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));

    return $rules;
}
```

I already created AdminUsersFixture and AdminUsersTableTest.
In AdminUsersTableTest I already load AdminUsersFixture.

I am able to test default validation by below method

```
public function testValidationDefault()
{
        $data = [
            'name' => 'lorem',
            'email' => 'jone@test.com',
            'password' => 'Lorem_ipsum',
            'status' => 1,
            'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'modified' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ];
        $adminUsers = $this->AdminUsers->newEntity($data);
        $this->assertEmpty($adminUsers->getErrors());
}
```

Now how I will write a test case method to test cakephp buildRules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation rules are applied when patching/creating an entity, they are ment to validate request data. Application rules are being applied when saving entities, they are ment to validate data/application integrity.

So you would save an entity (it *must* not have any validation errors, otherwise the saving operation will bail out before applying application rules), and then check for possible errors on the entity.

For example:

```php
public function testApplicationRulesEmailsMustBeUnique()
{
    $adminUser = $this->AdminUsers->newEmptyEntity();
    $adminUser->email = 'already@existing.email';
    
    $this->assertFalse($this->AdminUsers->save($adminUser));
    
    $this->assertSame(
        ['_isUnique' => 'This value is already in use'],
        $adminUser->getError('email')
    );
}
```

```php
public function testSavingSucceeds()
{
    $data = [
        'name' => 'lorem',
        'email' => 'jone@test.com',
        'password' => 'Lorem_ipsum',
        'status' => 1,
        'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'modified' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ];
    $adminUser = $this->AdminUsers->newEntity($data);
    
    $this->assertInstanceOf(
        \Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface::class, 
        $this->AdminUsers->save($adminUser)
    );
    $this->assertEmpty($adminUser->getErrors());
    
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `checkRules` method , checkRules will return bool for create , update or delete.

```
public function testBuildRulesEmailUnique()
{   
        $this->assertFalse( 
            $this->AdminUsers->checkRules(
               $this->AdminUsers->newEntity([
                   'email' => 'jone@test.com'
               ])
        ));
}
```